# Ошибки в подключении к базе данных.

Tags: php

Файл db.php содержит ошибку или ошибки. Необходимо подключиться к базе. Необходимо это подключение для того, чтобы в итоге пользователь мог бы воспользоваться поиском, а так как база к базе не получается подключиться, то это становиться проблематично. 
Существует код подключения:

```
<?php
$db_name            = 'infoin';
$db_host            = 'localhost';
$db_user            = 'admin';
$db_password        = '123456';


$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
mysqli_select_db($db_name,$link) or die("Нет соединения с БД " .mysqli_error());
mysqli_query("SET names cp1251");

  class db {

    function PDO__construct()
    {
        global $dbh;
        if (!is_null($dbh)) return;
        $dbh = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME);
        mysqli_query('SET NAMES utf8');
    }

    function select_list($query)
    {
        $q = mysqli_query($query);
        if (!$q) return null;
        $ret = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($ret, $row);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($q);
        return $ret;
    }
  }
?>
```

Я уже один из подсказок нашел, оказалось, что mysqli необходимо, я в документация подсмотрел. Однако ошибка не пропадает. Так как код считает сверху вниз, то ошибок может ещё тут есть. Вот и получается, что выводит две ошибки. Не знаю наверно что-то фундаментально поменять или подход, а может просто какое-то небольшое исправление... Если ещё есть какие-то ошибки ниже mysqli_select_db() и mysqli_error(), тоже было хорошо чтобы нашлись, а то база никак не подключается(((.
Вот эти ошибки выводит:
      Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\OSPanel\domains\devitera.com\include\db.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in D:\OSPanel\domains\devitera.com\include\db.php on line 9
Нет соединения с БД

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в строке 9 указывает на неверный параметр `mysqli_select_db` имеет такой формат записи `mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )` [вот документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php).
У `mysqli_query` тоже такая же ошибка `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )` [документация тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php).
Советую вам почитать про подключение и запросы к базе поподробнее - [Использование mysqli](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=010)